# fread() and read() get different data

Tags: c, linux, fread

I have a program to detect keyboard.

At first,I used `read()` to read `struct input_event` from keyboard device and it works well.

Then I tried to replace `read()` with `fread()`. It got wrong data.

The demo is below. To reproduct the bug, you need to exchange `/dev/input/event0` with your keyboard dev and run it with `sudo`.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define USE_FREAD

static void check_keyboard (int fd)
{
    static struct input_event event;
    
#ifdef USE_READ
    {
        //use read(). it works well.
        if (read (fd, &event, sizeof (event)) == -1)
            perror ("read()"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
#else
#ifdef USE_FREAD
    {
        //use fread(). it gets wrong data
        int cloned = dup (fd);
        if (cloned == -1)
            perror ("dup()"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    
        FILE *file = fdopen (cloned, "r");
        if (file == NULL)
            perror ("fdopen()"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    
        if (fread (&event, sizeof (event), 1, file) != 1) {
            if (feof (file))
                fprintf (stderr, "fread() got EOF"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
            else if (ferror (file))
                fprintf (stderr, "fread() failed\n"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        if (fclose (file) != 0)
            perror ("fclose()"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    
        puts ("fread() over");
    }
#endif
#endif
    
    if (event.type != EV_KEY)
        return;
    switch (event.value) {
        case 0:
            puts ("key released");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf ("key pressed, code:%d\n", event.code);
            break;
        case 2:
            puts ("repeat automatically");
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int fd = open ("/dev/input/event0", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
        perror ("open()"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        
    for (; ;) {
        check_keyboard (fd);
    }
    
    if (close (fd) != 0)
        perror ("close()"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

It can detect keyboard event if `USE_READ` is defined. And it only print "fread() over" if `USE_FREAD` is defined.

I tried to use gdb to watch the value of `event`. But there are many other events confusing the data.

My environment: debian 12, gcc 12.2.0 , kernel 6.1.0-7-amd64 .

Comment: then don't use `fread`

Comment: @user253751 I use it because I'm not clear about how to deal with `read()`. For example, It may be interruptd and set errno to `EINTR`.

Comment: @barbyQAQ if you're not sure how to deal with `read`, why are you sure you can deal with `fread`?

Comment: You do not perform sufficient error checking for `read()` (you do not test for a short read), and you perform none for `dup()`, `fdopen()`, or `fread()`.  Proper checks might reveal the nature of the issue.  And if `fread()` is in fact reading an item, surely you could look into the details of the event that it actually does read.  That is likely to be informative.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I thought `fread()` won't be interrupted.Or it can restart automatically. I usually use 'ferror()' to check for errors and exit if any occurs。

Comment: The code presented does not contain any `ferror()` calls, and in any case, you should be using functions' *return values* as the primary status indicator.  `ferror()` is best used for distinguishing between normal end-of-input and I/O errors, in cases where you already know that I/O was not (wholly) successful.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I used to check the return value is corresponding with my expectaion. `fread (&event, sizeof (event), 1, file)` returns 1 and `fread (&event, 1, sizeof(event), file)` will return 24,which is equal to `sizeof(event)` on my os.

Comment: When reading from devices rather than reading from actual files, `fread` is not at all equivalent to `read`, because `fread` uses a buffer. You can use `setvbuf` for changing the buffer size.

Comment: @barbyQAQ, the former is the correct call, the latter not. And if you used to check the result then why don't you *still* do it?  That's not a debugging measure, but rather a necessity for robust code.  The same for testing the return values of the other functions.

Comment: @barbyQAQ The code you've shown looks fine as far as it goes, and I would expect it to work with either the `read` or `fread` branches.  Whatever is causing it not to work one way, is probably due to something unique to your environment, that we can't see.  So based on what you've told us, we can't help you.  Do please take all the hints that have been given here — they're all good ones.  (And definitely check the error returns of everything in sight.)

Comment: It's true that `fread()` uses a buffer, @Jabberwocky, but it's not clear to me how that would be responsible for the OP's issue, and I think "not at all equivalent" is an overstatement.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you! I solveed it. Just disable buffering with `setvbuf (file, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`  and it will work.

Comment: @SteveSummi You are right. Sometimes I slack off when writting temporary code. I will check return value as possiable as I can.

Comment: Not checking return status of basic functions when writing "temporary code" is generally a recipe for giving yourself more debugging headaches and wasting more time figuring out what is going wrong.  The minimal extra time taken to put the error checking in when you write the code the first time generally saves a lot of time later.

Comment: @JohnBollinger short read cannot occur for special files like this one

Comment: Is that so, @user253751? On every version of every operating system that supports these interfaces, past, present, & future?  Among the principles of robust coding is to make as few assumptions as possible, and yours is an assumption that does not need to be made.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes.

Answer (score 1):

I have sovled it according to suggestions in comments.

Just disable the buffer with `setvbuf()`:

```c
#ifdef USE_FREAD
    {
        //use fread(). it gets right data now.
        int cloned = dup (fd);
        if (cloned == -1)
            perror ("dup()"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    
        FILE *file = fdopen (cloned, "r");
        if (setvbuf (file, NULL, _IONBF, 0) != 0)
            perror ("setvbuf()"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    
        if (fread (&event, sizeof (event), 1, file) != 1) {
            if (feof (file))
                fprintf (stderr, "fread() got EOF"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            else if (ferror (file))
                fprintf (stderr, "fread() failed\n"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
        if (fclose (file) != 0)
            perror ("fclose()"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
#endif
```

By the way, check the return value, please.